# When there is no item to display in your activity Section, What should I say?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, internet

> "You have not performed any activity"

OR

> "You have not performed any action"

OR

> "There is no item in your activity tab"

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

> **There is no activity to display**

This works fine unless you want to underscore that it was the *user* who didn't perform any activity, as opposed to the system, for example.

From the three options you presented, **"You have not performed any activity"** is correct, too.

"You have not performed any action" should be "You have not performed any actions" (plural.)

"There is no item in your activity tab" should be "There are no items in your activity tab" (again, plural.)

But the last two are a bit inelegant, even after the grammar has been corrected.

Comment: "There is no activity to display" works better. Otherwise you're telling the user what they have or have not done e.g. you have not performed any activity. Better to just tell them what information you have

Comment: @BrianBishop I work in a software company, and typically I would agree. But sometimes context may call for the active voice.

Comment: @A.P., Thanks for your help pal. Let say if this in context of points. How should I say "You have not earned any points yet" or "There are no earned points yet"

Comment: @Ridlr In this case I would definitely prefer the active voice and go with "You have not earned any points yet". This tells the user *they* are responsible for earning the points, it's up to *them*, so go and earn some! I think this would work better in context of gamification.

Comment: If I can get only 1 point at a time. should it be "point" or "points"?

Comment: @Ridlr Not 100% sure what you mean, can you provide a sentence?

Comment: @A.P. 1) "You have not earned any point yet" or "You haven't earned any points yet". 2) "There is no activity to display" or "there are no activities to display".

Comment: @Ridlr "You have not earned any points yet" and "There is no activity to display" are the way to go. "There are no activities to display" is grammatical, but does not fit the context very well.

Comment: @A.P. Thank you very much AP for sorting this out. Really Appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: @Ridlr no problem, glad I could help.

Comment: It's just that saying "you have not performed any activity yet" may be confusing. The user may well have performed an activity, just not one that has been recorded.

Comment: @BrianBishop Good point.

Comment: @A.P. The user might think, wow, I didn't perform any activities, I mustn't have logged in, or come to work today. Then they could get worried, and wonder if they are really there at all!! It could snowball very quickly